Calling API every 2 seconds increases browser resources using rxjs in Angular
I need to show updated data on this particular page without refreshing. I am using rxjs method to call data every 2 seconds. It's working Great.
However, I noticed that my Chrome network resources is increasing by the minute. It started from somewhere around 3mb to 34mb within a few minutes. See screenshot.

Is this a normal behaviour? I have to keep the browser open for 8+ hours and looking at this, the resources will increase to a few hundred+ MBs.
How do I decrease the resources being taken by this?
This is my HTML file:
<div *ngFor="let item of currPatients">
  <div *ngIf="item.isQueue !== false">
    <div class="col">
      <strong>{{item.sequenceId}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      {{item.registration.registrationId}}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      {{item.registration?.firstName}} {{item.registration?.lastName}}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      {{item.date | date: "dd MMM, yyyy '/' hh:mm a"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      {{item.isQueue}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This is my TS file:
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Opd } from 'src/app/interfaces/opd';
import { CoreService } from 'src/app/services/core.service';
import { interval, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, debounceTime, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public currPatients: Opd[] = [];
  public opd = {} as Opd;
  private pollingSubscription!: Subscription;
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(
    private coreService: CoreService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.startPolling();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(); // Signal the observables to complete
    this.destroy$.complete(); // Clean up the subject
  }

  private startPolling(): void {
    this.pollingSubscription = interval(2000).pipe(
      debounceTime(1000), // Optional: Add debounceTime to reduce rapid emissions
      switchMap(() => this.coreService.getOpdsbyQueue()), // Automatically cancel previous request
      takeUntil(this.destroy$) // Automatically unsubscribe when destroy$ emits
    ).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.currPatients = res.data;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error fetching patients', err);
      }
    });
  }
}


Is currPatients only ever going to grow in size? That might explain.

Yes but as you can see <div *ngIf="item.isQueue !== false">, it hides when it becomes false. Should it be handled from the TS file?

Yeah so a few things here. Having really long list in the view will definitely affect performances. Try to either add pagination or virtual scrolling but keep the view to a minimum number of items. As an extra precaution, add a trackBy to your ngFor, this shall help to avoid rendering all the array every time you refresh the list. Then it should be a lot better

Code looks fine, maybe garbage collection has not run, hence the size is not reduced, as a test you can leave it on (for said duration) and it should not crash, then your fine.
Try Long Polling instead of short polling, like 15 seconds, since such a short interval might overload the server, when there are multiple users.
Else you need to go for a web socket solution, but long polling is a simpler solution.

Hi, Thank you so much for the feedback. I will leave it for about an hour and see what happens. As for my work; 15 seconds is too long. I'll perhaps increase it to 5 seconds.
I'll keep the question open for now hoping for any other responses from other members although your answer is credible enough. Thank you once again.

@ElaineByene no problem!
